# How do i loop through a json object after converting to php multidimensional array?

Tags: php, json, laravel, multidimensional-array

```
{
"timeZone":"Africa/Lagos",
"days":
[
    {
        "Monday":["07:30 AM","08:00 AM","08:30 AM","09:00 AM","09:30 AM","10:00 AM","10:30 AM","11:00 AM","11:30 AM","12:00 PM","12:30 PM","01:00 PM","01:30 PM","02:00 PM","02:30 PM","03:00 PM","03:30 PM","04:00 PM","04:30 PM","05:00 PM","05:30 PM","06:00 PM","06:30 PM","07:00 PM"]
    },
    {
        "Tuesday":["07:30 AM","08:00 AM","08:30 AM","09:00 AM","09:30 AM","10:00 AM","10:30 AM","11:00 AM","11:30 AM","12:00 PM","12:30 PM","01:00 PM","01:30 PM","02:00 PM","02:30 PM","03:00 PM","03:30 PM","04:00 PM","04:30 PM","05:00 PM","05:30 PM","06:00 PM","06:30 PM","07:00 PM"]
    },
    {
        "Wednesday":["07:30 AM","08:00 AM","08:30 AM","09:00 AM","09:30 AM","10:00 AM","10:30 AM","11:00 AM","11:30 AM","12:00 PM","12:30 PM","01:00 PM","01:30 PM","02:00 PM","02:30 PM","03:00 PM","03:30 PM","04:00 PM","04:30 PM","05:00 PM","05:30 PM","06:00 PM","06:30 PM","07:00 PM"]
    },
    {
        "Thursday":["07:30 AM","08:00 AM","08:30 AM","09:00 AM","09:30 AM","10:00 AM","10:30 AM","11:00 AM","11:30 AM","12:00 PM","12:30 PM","01:00 PM","01:30 PM","02:00 PM","02:30 PM","03:00 PM","03:30 PM","04:00 PM","04:30 PM","05:00 PM","05:30 PM","06:00 PM","06:30 PM","07:00 PM"]
    },
    {
        "Friday":["07:30 AM","08:00 AM","08:30 AM","09:00 AM","09:30 AM","10:00 AM","10:30 AM","11:00 AM","11:30 AM","12:00 PM","12:30 PM","01:00 PM","01:30 PM","02:00 PM","02:30 PM","03:00 PM","03:30 PM","04:00 PM","04:30 PM","05:00 PM","05:30 PM","06:00 PM","06:30 PM","07:00 PM"]
    }
]
}
```

How do i loop through this to get the values of all the days and their times? `$result['timeZone']` prints out the value correctly but `$result['days']` does not.

```
 <?php 
   $result=json_decode($doctor->time_availiable,true);
   echo $result['timeZone'];

    foreach ($result['days'] as $key => $value) {
       echo $key.':'.$value;
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: Is `$doctor` an instance of a `Doctor` model record? Also, is `time_available` a `text/json` field in your database?

Comment: Yes $doctor an instance of a Doctor model and yes time_available a text/json field in your database

Comment: You can use [casts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) to auto decode json when accessing the data.

Comment: Thanks, i will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the `$value` inside the `foreach()` method is an array and can't be echoed.

Try this:

```
<?php 
   $result=json_decode($doctor->time_availiable,true);
   echo $result['timeZone'];

    foreach ($result['days'] as $dayFromArray) {
        foreach($dayFromArray as $dayFromObject => $hours) {
            foreach($hours as $hour) {
                echo $day.':'.$hour."\n";   
            }
            echo "\n";
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: I tried this it gives me this error "Array to string conversion". Meanwhile $key produces the value "0,1,2,3,4" Instead of Monday Tuesday....

Comment: You're right, my bad, i edited my answer to get the right results. changed variable names too so it's more clear

Comment: the tricky situation here is that each day is in his own json object.

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
$results = json_decode($doctor->time_availiable, true);

foreach ($results as $key => $result)
{

    foreach ($results['days'] as $dayName => $timeAry)
    {
        //in timeAry you will get respective day times
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will get you all the way down to the hours, please note **some of the json decodes as an object**, not an array

```
$result=json_decode($doctor->time_availiable,true);
```

echo $result->timeZone;

```
foreach ($result['days'] as $key => $value) {
   foreach ($value as $weekday => $hours) {
        echo $weekday;
        foreach($hours as $hour) {
            echo $hour . ', ';
        }
   }    
}
```

Comment: This worked  but i had to change $result->days to $result['days']. Thanks so much!